# System.Data.SqlClient.Exception ( 0x80131904) String or binary would be terminated

Tags: c#, sql-server

i have the following code and when i execute it i get the following error : 
System.Data.SqlClient.Exception ( 0x80131904) String or binary would be terminated

```
form1.con.Open();
command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE sucursale SET nume_sucursala='" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "',sucursala_coord='" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + "',mida='" + textBox4.Text.Trim() + "',flex='" + textBox5.Text.Trim() + "',nr_sucursala='" + textBox6.Text.Trim() + "',director='" + textBox7.Text.Trim() + "',tel_director='" + textBox8 + "',director_adj='" + textBox9.Text.Trim() + "',tel_director_adj='" + textBox10.Text.Trim() + "',adresa='" + textBox14.Text.Trim() + "',telefon='" + textBox15.Text.Trim() + "',fax='" + textBox16.Text.Trim() + "',u1_days='" + textBox26.Text.Trim() + "',u1_company='" + textBox17.Text.Trim() + "',u2_days='" + textBox27.Text.Trim() + "',u2_company='" + textBox18.Text.Trim() + "',u3_days='" + textBox28.Text.Trim() + "',u3_company='" + textBox19.Text.Trim() + "',u4_days='" + textBox29.Text.Trim() + "',u4_company='" + textBox20.Text.Trim() + "',u5_days='" + textBox30.Text.Trim() + "',u5_company='" + textBox21.Text.Trim() + "',u6_days='" + textBox31.Text.Trim() + "',u6_company='" + textBox22.Text.Trim() + "',retea_interna='" + textBox23.Text.Trim() + "',timer='" + textBox24.Text.Trim() + "',program_clienti='" + textBox25.Text.Trim() + "',contact_extra='" + textBox11.Text.Trim() + "',functie_contact_extra='" + textBox12.Text.Trim() + "',telefon_contact_extra='" + textBox13.Text.Trim() + "' WHERE nr_sucursala = '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem + "'", form1.con);
form1.da2.UpdateCommand = command;

form1.da2.Update(form1.ds2, "sucursale");
form1.con.Close();
```

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't String or binary would be truncated? The truncated error usually means that you are attempting to insert data that is larger than the size of a column. I would go through your database and check the size of each of these columns and compare them to the data that you attempted to insert.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly; **don't concatenate user input**; that should be parameterized:

```
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = @"
UPDATE [SomeTable]
SET [SomeColumn] = @someColumn
WHERE [Id] = @id";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("someColumn", usersNastyText);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", recordId);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The error means that the text in one of the boxes is longer than the declared column. Either expand the column in the database, or validate the length of the text in the boxes before sending to the server.

[Obligatory XKCD reference](http://xkcd.com/327/)

[image: Exploits of a mom]